# GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent won't shutdown console application

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to make a C application that closes another console application by sending Control + C to it but my code doesn't always seem to work. The program I am trying to shutdown with Control + C is a game server process.. The only way to shut it down is by pressing Control + C. I want to avoid using TerminateProcess because the program does some form of cleanup code when Control + C is pressed and I'm afraid TerminateProcess will corrupt its database files. According to all the research I've done, GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent is the right function to simulate Control + C but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
FreeConsole();
if(AttachConsole(dwProcessID))
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE);
    if (!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0))
        return;

    FreeConsole();
    if (WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 30000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        Log("The process did not terminate on its own.");
    }
}
// output: The process did not terminate on its own.
```

The above code is only partially working.. I know this because it causes the console app to spit out information about drivers shutting down but it wont proceed with the full cleanup & shutdown code. Why isn't my code working? Also, FreeConsole is causing my own console to disappear although it still runs in the background. Is there a function I can call to get it back?

Comment: *The above code is only partially working..* - what is the mean. vs *but it is not working.*

Comment: `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)` sends the event to all process groups in the console. Individual processes may ignore it, in particular if they're started as a new group via `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` and do not  manually enable Ctrl+C at startup. But obviously this program is not ignoring Ctrl+C since it appears to work partially.

Comment: Probably its console control handler is setting a global flag to signal a graceful shutdown. I assume a normal Ctrl+C usually works, so I'd wager that a thread is blocked reading from the console via `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`.  Annoyingly `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` does not cancel a console read like a real Ctrl+C. Check the stack trace for all threads in Process Explorer to confirm that at least one is blocked in a console read.

Comment: So get this... Sometimes when Control + C is sent to the application it will shutdown as expected but other times it does not shutdown. Instead, the console app that is supposed to shutdown will stay open. That's why I said it's partially working. Oddly changing the time on the operating system seems to have solved my issue for now.

Comment: You may have to give up on `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` and do something less clean, such as getting the console window handle via `GetConsoleWindow()` and posting Ctrl+C as keyboard input directly to the window. This lets the console itself generate the event and cancel pending reads.

Comment: To keep the current console referenced and allow re-attaching to it, you can spawn another console process that does nothing but reference the console by waiting. It could be your own executable with a command-line argument that tells it to just wait. Keep the process handle open to ensure the PID remains valid and doesn't get reused if someone terminates the reference process. When you want to attach back to your original console, call `FreeConsole()`, `AttachConsole(reference_pid)`, `TerminateProcess(reference_handle, 0)`, and `CloseHandle(reference_handle)`.

Comment: Thanks Eryk. I'll give that a try.